# Carpeta temporal de imágenes en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, imagen

¿Cómo de importante es la carpeta temporal para subir imágenes en una base de datos mysql? Algunos foros y tutoriales no crean la carpeta y suben la imagen sin esta.

Comment: ¿Cómo la suben estos foros y tutoriales? Es perfectamente posible hacerlo sin ella, pero sin otros ejemplos no podemos comparar.

Comment: Aun que la pregunta no está clara, decir que aún que tu no designes una carpeta temporal, php lo hará por ti. Cuando envías un archivo al servidor esto lo almacena temporalmente en un directorio, elegido por ti directamente o por php. Vease: http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente cuando implementamos un sistema de subida de imágenes con php.

- Lo normal es almacenar los ficheros(**imagenes**) en la carpeta /tmp que es donde van a
  parar los ficheros que le enviamos por $_FILES automaticamente.
- Mueves los ficheros(**.jpg**,**.exe**,**.rar**) a la carpeta donde necesites
  almacenarlo.
- Obtiene la ruta de la imagen en el servidor y almacenarla en la base de datos.

Al tener los ficheros subidos en /tmp nos olvidamos de tener que borrar esos ficheros porque son temporales y se van borrando solos.
El motivo por el que se van guardando hay es porque PHP tiene definido por defecto esa carpeta para la transmisión de ficheros via POST.

$_FILES y $_POST se envían en la misma petición eso es lo que tienen en común para poder transferir tanto String como Binario.

Existen formas mas complejas de enviar imagenes a php como por ejemplo convertir la imagen a **base64** enviarla como String y php convertirte ese String en Binario. Evitando que ese fichero pase por $_FILES y todo pase por $_POST que serian peticiones AJAX

Comment: En realidad no es que los archivos en `/tmp` se borren solos, sino que al usar [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php) lo sacas de `/tmp` en vez de copiarlo

Comment: Cierto, de esa forma dejas la carpeta vacia pero no hay que olvidar que PHP dice:  The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed. 
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Tienes razón... ahora que lo pienso, en mi workflow yo muevo el archivo, lo manipulo y luego lo borro de la ubicación final. Por eso pensé que el paso de borrarlo era necesario. Me enseñaste algo nuevo :)